# representation of gene and chromosomes in genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I'm fairly new to genetic algorithm and would like to ask one question. All the resources on genetic algorithm I came across talked about using binary number or real number to represent gene. I'm working on itinerary generator that makes use of genetic algorithm. Normally, itinerary consists of point of interests, but mine is made up of cities that is represented by a binary string. Each bit position encodes information such as if the city has museums or not, or if it has car rental service or not. For example, if the city has a car rental, bit position that represents car rental service will be set to 1. The number of cities consist in an itinerary is determined by the duration of stay. So, in terms of genetic algorithm representation, each itinerary represents a chromosome and city represents gene. I haven't seen that kind of representation in any resources that I have read(each gene is a binary string and each chromosome is made up of multiple binary strings.).  So I would like to know if I'm on the right track or not.

Edit : So for crossover, it'd be between multiple bit strings. For mutation, it's basically replacing an existing city with another city from the population.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could represent it as a string of integers, each of the integer being the integer representation of the binary number that describes the city. Than you are good to go - crossover is just crossover and mutation you described as changing a city (i.e. one number) to another one.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Kind of make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The representation of your chromosome can be anything. Having it represented as a bit string is convenient, easy to understand, and easy to manipulate if you have something that can already manipulate bit strings.

But it could be anything. Usually it's a collection of some data type (or several different ones put together).

What representation you choose will influence how it mutates and what the shape of the fitness landscape is.